# Intermittent failed attempts to login to SMB using Windows account name

Tags: windows, nas, smb, file-server, windows-authentication

I'm having a problem with Windows 10 intermittently trying to login to a file server (SMB/CIFS) which I only found out about because the file server is a QNAP NAS with SMB shares and the NAS has security that blocks the IP (of the Windows 10 machine) for x amount of time after 5 failed attempts.

Here's a bit more about the setup (I'm replacing specifics with faked details):

- The NAS has a user account set up: johnny.
- The Windows machine has a user account: Johnny. Notice the capitalization difference.
- I've already successfully created drive mappings under the Johnny Windows account by explicitly providing the NAS user account/credentials: johnny/passwordOnNAS. I set it to reconnect at logon.

Most of the time, there are no issues. Johnny starts up, logs on to Windows, and has his drive mappings there and they work.

However, occasionally, the NAS reports that it is blocking the Windows 10 machine's IP because of too many failed attempts. Occasionally = once every few days, more or less. Johnny starts and logs onto the Windows machine every day...sometimes more than once per day.

I checked the Windows event viewer and couldn't find anything helpful there. I also didn't know exactly which log to look in for where helpful info would be.

On the NAS side, the "username" that is shown to have tried and caused the IP ban is "Johnny". The NAS "username" that works and normally accesses shared files via SMB is "johnny".

So, I think this has to do with Windows "occasionally" trying to connect to the NAS SMB share as the Windows username "Johnny". I don't know if it's trying the corresponding Windows password or no password at all...neither will work because the NAS doesn't recognize that username because it's case sensitive...only "johnny" maps to a user on the NAS.

I'm hoping to get some advice how I can stop these occasional failed attempts or how I can diagnose exactly what is trying to connect and failing.

Comment: Why not make the user names identical?

Comment: I thought of that. While that approach might help prove that it is or isn't tied to the Windows account that is surreptitiously trying to authenticate, it doesn't gain me insight into why. I was looking for specific insight in terms of troubleshooting by going through event viewer logs or monitoring network traffic or monitoring processes in use at the time of the event or something like that. Or maybe someone has seen this exact behaviour before and can point to a smoking gun. That's what I was hoping for.